# eliminate space after form element

Tags: forms, space

I have a form element in a table cell which is giving me extra unwanted space at the end. I have tried changing my style sheet to form{ margin-bottom:0;} How do i eliminate the space after the form element if it's in a table cell?

```
echo '<tr id="'.$serial.'" class="more"><td colspan="4" valign="top"><form id="newcredit'.$serial.'" name="newcredit'.$serial.'" style="margin-bottom:0">';

echo '<input type="text" id="Label" name="Label" style="width:75px" onKeyPress="return submitcredit(this.event, '.$serial.')" />';
echo '<img src="plussm.png" id="'.$serial.'" title="Add Credit" onclick="creditadd(this.id), removewatermark(this.value, this.id)" /></form>';
```

Server Database call... foreach(blahs as blah)...

```
echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="text" id="'.$creditid.'" name="Label" style="width:75px" value="'.$recordLabel).'" onchange="creditupdate(this.id, this.name, this.value)" />';
echo '</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean extra space at the end or on the below the form?

I am having a similar issue where I have two table cells side by side, and the first cell has a width of 100%.

There is one button in the second cell, but there is a gap between the right-hand side of the button and the end of the cell.

Adding buttons to the cell widens the gap at the end of the last button.